# how to use OnLoad to show loader when image is loading in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show loader till the time image get loads. I tried but it's not working.

```
const showLoader = () => {
    return (
      <div className="border-2">
        <Loader />
      </div>
    );
  };

 <img
 className="w-full"
 src={item?.image}
 onClick={() => setId(item?.id)}
 onLoad={() => showLoader()}
  />
```

Comment: onLoad is called after the image gets loaded

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The onLoad event will be triggered once the image is loaded - https://idiallo.com/javascript/img-detect-loaded

NOTE - Do not conditionally render the img tag. The onLoad event will not be triggered if the img tag does not exist in the DOM. Rather, use the display property to set the loading state

Try this -

```
function Test() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  return <>
    <div style={{display: loading ? "block" : "none"}}>
       {showLoader()}
    </div>
    <div style={{display: loading ? "none" : "block"}}>
        <img 
          className="w-full"
          src={item?.image}
          onClick={() => setId(item?.id)}
          onLoad={() => setLoading(false)} />
    </div>
  </>;
}
```